# what this code do

Tags: qt

What is the correct way to convert this code to Qt

```
base64_encode(unsigned char const* bytes_to_encode, unsigned int in_len)
{

 while (in_len--) {
      std::cout<< *(bytes_to_encode++)<<std::endl;
}
}
```

what is *(bytes_to_encode++) do

Comment: Qt is a library, not a language.

Comment: Perhaps learn the language before trying to use it?

Comment: i know qt is skd and i know the language but this code is ambigous for me thanks

Comment: @user522745 If something like a simple pointer operation and a postincrement is ambiguous for you, then you **don't know the language.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Qt is a GUI framework, I don't understand why you should have to convert that function (I mean that nothing in Qt is going to stop you from using that function as-is).

Anyways:

`bytes_to_encode` is a character pointer, so `*bytes_to_encode` will return the character pointed to by `bytes_to_encode`.  `bytes_to_encode++` will return the pointer and then increment it (ie, make it point to the next location. `*(bytes_to_encode++)` combines both actions, ie it returns the character pointed to by `bytes_to_encode` and then increments the pointer, so that next time the next character is returned.

Comment: it's a C code do base64 and i want to port it to Qt

Answer (score 1):

The expression `*(bytes_to_encode++)` does two things:

`*bytes_to_encode` will read the byte at the position in memory where the `bytes_to_encode` pointer points to.

`bytes_to_encode++` will increment the pointer `bytes_to_encode` by 1 (since it's an unsigned char value). This is called a post-increment operator.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what your function has to do with Base64-Encoding. However, have a look at [QByteArray::fromBase64](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#fromBase64) and [QByteArray::toBase64](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#toBase64):

```
const QByteArray bytes_to_encode = "your data";
const QByteArray encoded = bytes_to_encode.toBase64();
std::cout << encoded.constData() << std::endl;
```

To decode:

```
const QByteArray encoded = "eW91cl9kYXRh";
const QByteArray decoded = QByteArray::fromBase64( encoded );
std::cout << decoded.constData() << std::endl;
```

Comment: yes QbyteArray do base64 by default thanks